# Parsing a String using BigQuery - of format "121,131,111=1600" for isntance

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a field in BigQuery that has values like this

"1,121,131,215=121"
"1,16,17,18,19,20,20,31,1411=215"

I have to extract the value that is key value for 215 -
in the first case it is 121
in the second case it is 1411

Looking for a solution to do this in BQ, really appreciate all the help!

Thanks!

Comment: logic is not clear - please clarify and maybe add few more examples

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to find last number before `=`, here's what you could do:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getLastElement(arr ARRAY<STRING>)
AS (arr[OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr)-1)]);

WITH data AS (SELECT "1,121,131,215=121" s 
UNION ALL SELECT "1,16,17,18,19,20,20,31,1411=215")
SELECT getLastElement(split(split(s, '=')[OFFSET(0)], ','))
FROM data;
```

Comment: if this would be a case - the expected result would be  215 and 1411, but OP is looking for 121 and 1411 respectively. agree?